# Inserting data into a custom object

Tags: ios, nsarray

I am still somewhat new to ObjC, so please forgive me if my terminology is off.

I have a webservice which returns the following event data in an array:

> - eventName
> - eventAddress
> - eventCity

The webservice array varies in size from time to time, depending on how many events are happening on a certain day.

My problem is that I need to pull this webservice data into a custom class(RandomEvent) automatically, but I'm not sure how to do it exactly.

I can do it manually like this, but since the size of the webservice return array varies, it doesn't make sense to do it this way(see below):

```
- (NSArray *)todaysEvents {
    RandomEvent *event1 = [RandomEvent new];
    [event1 setName:eventName[0]];
    [event1 setAddress:eventAddress[0]];
    [event1 setCity:eventCity[0]];

    RandomEvent *event2 = [RandomEvent new];
    [event2 setName:eventName[1]];
    [event2 setAddress:eventAddress[1]];
    [event2 setCity:eventCity[1]];

    RandomEvent *event3 = [RandomEvent new];
    [event3 setName:eventName[2]];
    [event3 setAddress:eventAddress[2]];
    [event3 setCity:eventCity[2]];

    return @[event1, event2, event3];
}
```

I know that I will have to iterate over the webservice array, but that's as far as I can get. What is the best way to assign the array values to my custom class? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you code:

```
- (NSArray *)todaysEvents {
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i<eventName.count; i++) {
        RandomEvent *event = [RandomEvent new];
        [event setName:eventName[i]];
        [event setAddress:eventAddress[i]];
        [event setCity:eventCity[i]];
        [resultArray addObject:event];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:resultArray];
}
```

But as I understand, you are trying to parse received JSON into objects manually. It can takes a long time for you. Try to use mapping frameworks like this one https://github.com/EasyMapping/EasyMapping .

Comment: Oh. I think it because we were answering in one time. Thanks for downvote btw

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `eventName eventAddress eventCity` have identical lengths, we can iterate over them pretty easily. A mutable array can be used to hold all of the `RandomEvent` objects that are created. Note that there is also a safety check in case one of the eventAddress or eventCity arrays is a different length than the others.

```
- (NSArray *)todaysEvents {
    NSMutableArray *eventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < eventName.count; i++){
        if ((eventAddress.count < i) && (eventCity.count < i)){
            RandomEvent *event = [[RandomEvent alloc] init];

            [event setName:eventName[i]];
            [event setAddress:eventAddress[i]];
            [event setCity:eventCity[i]];

            [eventsArray addObject:event];
        }
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:eventsArray];
}
```

Another suggestion would be to create the `RandomEvent` objects as soon as they are read from the web service. This way extra arrays won't have to be passed around.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to programming language. This is more OOP question

Yes, you are right you will have to iterate through the results to map between DTO to view Model. That may sound repeating but it is important/helpful to decouple DTO and view Models.

From you sample code it looks like you have multiple arrays, for eventName, eventAddress etc. 
 it is good practice to have one array of response object.
So structure should be Array of ResponseObjects

Class ResponseObject
@Property eventName
@Property eventAddress
@Property eventCity

**** pseudo code ****
- (NSArray*)mapDTOtoViewModel:(NSArray)_responseArray{
//Use initWithCapacity instead of init
  NSMutableArray viewModels = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[_responseArray count]];

//Use fast enumeration for better performance
for (Response *response in _responseArray){
    RandomEvent *event = [RandomEvent new];
    [event setName:response.eventName];
    [event setAddress:response.eventAddress];
    [event setCity:response.eventCity];

```
[viewModels addObject:event];
```

}
return viewModels;

}

Comment: Thank all of you. This was driving me nuts.